# Matplotlib Colorbar missing 1 required positional argument: 'mappable'

Tags: matplotlib, scatter-plot, python-3.8, colorbar

I would like to create a scatter chart for dataframe below:

```
df_sample.head(10)

    duration  distance speed
0   26.299999   3.569   8.1
1   6.000000    0.739   7.4
2   25.700001   2.203   5.1
3   34.400002   2.876   5.0
4   3.000000    0.656   13.1
5   29.299999   3.704   7.6
6   10.200000   2.076   12.2
7   4.000000    0.774   11.6
8   9.200000    1.574   10.3
9   10.800000   0.782   4.3
```

Almost get it done with codes below. I want to add colorbar to the figure based on speed (Yellow: Slowest & Blue : Fastest) and eventually I got an error at `fig.colorbar(ax=ax)` at the last line. Please advise: what is `mappable`?

```
with plt.style.context('seaborn-ticks'):

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (10, 6))

    ax.set_title('Relationship between Distance & Duration', fontdict={'fontsize': 18, 'fontweight': 'bold'}, loc='left', pad=20)
    ax.scatter(x=df_sample.duration.values, y=df_sample.distance.values, c=df_sample.speed.values, cmap=cm.YlGnBu)

    # remove top & right spines
    ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
    ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)

    # equivalent to 'sns.despine(offset = 5)'
    ax.spines['left'].set_position(('outward', 5))
    ax.spines['left'].set_linewidth(1.2)
    ax.spines['bottom'].set_position(('outward', 5))
    ax.spines['bottom'].set_linewidth(1.2)
    
    # set ticks & ticklabels
    xloc = np.arange(0, 45, 5)
    ax.set_xticks(xloc)
    ax.set_xticklabels(labels=xloc, fontdict={'fontsize': 12})
    ax.set_xlabel('Minute(s)', fontdict={'fontsize': 14, 'fontweight': 'bold'})
    
    yloc = np.arange(6)
    ylab = [f"{int(num)}" for num in yloc]
    ax.set_yticks(yloc)
    ax.set_yticklabels(labels=ylab, fontdict={'fontsize': 12})
    ax.set_ylabel("Distance (KM)" , fontdict={'fontsize': 14, 'fontweight': 'bold'})
    
    fig.colorbar(ax=ax);
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can assign your scatterplot to a variable, for instance:

```
sp=ax.scatter(x=df_sample.duration.values, y=df_sample.distance.values, c=df_sample.speed.values, cmap=cm.YlGnBu)
```

and then pass it as a [mappable object](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/cm_api.html#matplotlib.cm.ScalarMappable) to the colorbar:

```
fig.colorbar(sp)
```

Comment: thanks, it works. May I ask follow up questions? How to position the colorbar at the top of chart and resize it? Do you have any resources?

Comment: according to [this](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.4/gallery/axes_grid1/demo_colorbar_with_axes_divider.html):

`from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.axes_divider import make_axes_locatable`
...
move title up a little:
`ax.set_title('Relationship between Distance & Duration', fontdict={'fontsize': 18, 'fontweight': 'bold'}, loc='left', pad=20,y=1.05)`
...
you can play with params so you get a size you need:
`divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)`
`cax = divider.append_axes("top", size="2%", pad="5%")`
`fig.colorbar(sp,cax=cax, orientation="horizontal")`

Comment: thanks @YevKad. I will get my hands on it soon.